# Reduce : This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have a few expressions and need to get a final simplified (reduced,solved) results. I am new and tried/searched different ways for my problem but couldn't find the reason. These are my expressions:

```
R0 = FractionalPart[Log[5, x + (3/ 4)]] ==  FractionalPart[Log[5, xP + (3/ 4)]]
R1  = Log[5, xP + (3 / 4)] - Log[3, yP + ( 5 / 2)] == Log[5, x + (3 / 4)] - Log[3, y + ( 5 / 2)]
F = ( (x == xP && y == yP) || ( Exists[{xPP, yPP},  xPP < yPP && xP == 5 xPP + 3 && yP == 3 yPP + 5]))
R = R0 && R1 && F
Reduce[R && xP >= yP , {x, y, xP, yP}, Reals]
```

when I run this it takes a long time and seems infinite loop or something and never finishes. I also tried this

```
Reduce[R , Element[{x, y, xP, yP}, Reals]]
```

and it returns the error: **Reduce : This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce**
We expect two functions for xP and yP based on x and y, for each. I am sure there must be a final reduce for this problem because there was a code for it before, but we don't have that code at this moment, so I think my transformation to Mathematica MUST be wrong. Please help me through this.

2- How can I make sure that each single expression is error free?
Thanks a lot

EDITED : this new gives me an error, "This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve" does someone know why ?

```
Solve[FractionalPart (Log[5, x + (3/4)]) == FractionalPart (Log[5, X + (3/4)]) && 
Log[5, x + (3/4)] - Log[3, y + (5/2)] == Log[5, X + (3/4)] - Log[3, Y + (5/2)] &&
    ((x == X && y == Y)||(x < y && (X - 3)/5 < (Y - 5)/3)) && X >= Y,{X,Y}, Integers]
```

Comment: To clarify: you say that you (used to) have Mathematica code involving Reduce that was able to solve this problem, but you can't find that code anymore? Also, your second question is far too broad: 1) it is not generally possible to ensure that; 2) what "expression" do you refer to, and what do you mean by error-free? Syntactically correct?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant this was a problem which was working but now we dont have that old code,now I am doing by myself. I am editing the question. For The second one, I thought there might be one problem in one of the expressions, so we can check one by one rather than reduce the whole, maybe i am wrong. for example look at this example Reduce[FractionalPart[x/3] == FractionalPart[xP/3], {x,xP}, Reals]. This says cannot reduce... so i have a Fractional in first expression that I thought could be wrong. Thanks

Comment: I do not see that Exists[..] introduces any new information. Then, to simplify, `x + (3/ 4)` could be replaced by `x` `xP+ (3/ 4)`  by `xP`  ...

Comment: Could you look at my EDITED, thanks.